# Using Parsec to write a Read instance

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Using Parsec, I'm able to write a function of type `String -> Maybe MyType` with relative ease. I would now like to create a `Read` instance for my type based on that; however, I don't understand how `readsPrec` works or what it is supposed to do.

My best guess right now is that `readsPrec` is used to build a recursive parser from scratch to traverse a string, building up the desired datatype in Haskell. However, I already have a very robust parser who does that very thing for me. So how do I tell `readsPrec` to use my parser? What is the "operator precedence" parameter it takes, and what is it good for in my context?

If it helps, I've created a [minimal example on Github](https://gist.github.com/4634782). It contains a type, a parser, and a blank Read instance, and reflects quite well where I'm stuck.

(Background: The real parser is for Scheme.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I already have a very robust parser who does that very thing for me.

It's actually not that robust, your parser has problems with superfluous parentheses, it won't parse

```
((1) (2))
```

for example, and it will throw an exception on some malformed inputs, because

```
singleP = Single . read <$> many digit
```

may use `read "" :: Int`.

That out of the way, the precedence argument is used to determine whether parentheses are necessary in some place, e.g. if you have

```
infixr 6 :+:

data a :+: b = a :+: b

data C = C Int

data D = D C
```

you don't need parentheses around a `C 12` as an argument of `(:+:)`, since the precedence of application is higher than that of `(:+:)`, but you'd need parentheses around `C 12` as an argument of `D`.

So you'd usually have something like

```
readsPrec p = needsParens (p >= precedenceLevel) someParser
```

where `someParser` parses a value from the input without enclosing parentheses, and `needsParens True thing` parses a `thing` between parentheses, while `needsParens False thing` parses a `thing` *optionally* enclosed in parentheses [you should always accept more parentheses than necessary, `((((((1))))))` should parse fine as an `Int`].

Since the `readsPrec p` parsers are used to parse parts of the input as parts of the value when reading lists, tuples etc., they must return not only the parsed value, but also the remaining part of the input.

With that, a simple way to transform a `parsec` parser to a `readsPrec` parser would be

```
withRemaining :: Parser a -> Parser (a, String)
withRemaining p = (,) <$> p <*> getInput

parsecToReadsPrec :: Parser a -> Int -> ReadS a
parsecToReadsPrec parsecParser prec input
    = case parse (withremaining $ needsParens (prec >= threshold) parsecParser) "" input of
        Left _ -> []
        Right result -> [result]
```

If you're using GHC, it may however be preferable to use a `ReadPrec / ReadP` parser (built using `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP[rec]`) instead of a `parsec` parser and define `readPrec` instead of `readsPrec`.

Comment: My Git is just a minimal example, I didn't want to add too much code that isn't strictly relevant to the question. Don't worry about the real parser, that one's been read checked and QuickChecked. :-)

Comment: I don't think it should fail, a `Read` instance should not only parse the output of `show`, it should also parse excessively parenthesized input. Ultimately, it's your decision, but only parsing input with no superfluous parentheses would violate the principle of least surprise, IMO.

Comment: Good point. I guess reversing `Show` is secondary compared to least surprises.